# RoboSats without any BTC to start with?

Tags: transaction-fees, trading, buy-bitcoins

I want to buy BTC without KYC. Therefore I want to use RoboSats. However, RS charge a small fee (to be paid in sats) for each order. Since I don't have BTC to begin with, I cannot pay the fee. Is there a way to buy some BTC without KYC, so that I can start using RS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Bisq Wiki](https://bisq.wiki/Funding_your_wallet#How_to_Obtain_Your_First_Bitcoin) suggests several options: (Bisq requires a security deposit of bitcoin so it faces the same chicken-and-egg problem)

- Buy your first bitcoin from someone you trust, like friends and family.
- Use a Bitcoin ATM if you have one in your area that doesn't require identity verification for smaller purchases.
- Offer a product or service for bitcoin.
- Find someone to buy from at a local bitcoin meetup.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer!